# simplexml_load com problema no xmlns

Tags: php, xml

Já fiz de tudo que eu sabia mas está dando um erro dizendo que o xmlns não é absoluto. já verifiquei o xml e está correto agora  quando

simplexml_load_string(): namespace warning : xmlns: URI Cangooroo.Webservice.V2.Operator is not absolute

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Body>
        <createClientResponse xmlns="http://v2.services.cangooroo.net/">
            <createClientResult>
                <ClientID xmlns="Cangooroo.Webservice.V2.Operator"></ClientID>
                <ClientCode xmlns="Cangooroo.Webservice.V2.Operator"></ClientCode>
                <CompleteName xmlns="Cangooroo.Webservice.V2.Operator">xxxx</CompleteName>
                <Address xmlns="Cangooroo.Webservice.V2.Operator">yyy</Address>
                <Phone1 xmlns="Cangooroo.Webservice.V2.Operator">(11)11111-111</Phone1>
                <Email xmlns="Cangooroo.Webservice.V2.Operator">abc@abc.com.br</Email>
                <NotificationEmail xmlns="Cangooroo.Webservice.V2.Operator">abc@abc.com.br</NotificationEmail>
                <PaymentType xmlns="Cangooroo.Webservice.V2.Operator"></PaymentType>
                <CanSeeVoucher xmlns="Cangooroo.Webservice.V2.Operator"></CanSeeVoucher>
                <CityName xmlns="Cangooroo.Webservice.V2.Operator"></CityName>
                <CountryName xmlns="Cangooroo.Webservice.V2.Operator"></CountryName>
                <BaseId xmlns="Cangooroo.Webservice.V2.Operator">0</BaseId>
                <BaseName xmlns="Cangooroo.Webservice.V2.Operator" />
                <ExternalReference xmlns="Cangooroo.Webservice.V2.Operator"></ExternalReference>
            </createClientResult>
        </createClientResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Pois bem segundo a documentação seria esta uma das maneiras mas este erro pode se repetir para o resto e a documentação deles é diferente do que eu recebo no retorno....

```
$retorno = simplexml_load_string($xml_retorno);
```

Desta forma aceito sugestões.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> *Antes de qualquer coisa eu indico que leia a documentação da classe
> `SoapClient` e veja se não é o caminho mais adequado para o seu projeto.*

---

Caso `SoapClient` não se adeque ao seu projeto você pode ter em mãos dois problemas sérios e sem resolução, porém contornáveis. Um o contorno é simples e outro mais complicado.

O primeiro é o alerta com qual você se deparou:

> simplexml_load_string(): namespace warning : xmlns: URI
> Cangooroo.Webservice.V2.Operator is not absolute

Esse alerta ocorre porque a `libxml` identificou o namespace `Cangooroo.Webservice.V2.Operator` como uma URI relativa. **Esse é o problema fácil** pois para resolver basta transformar todas as referências a URI relativa `Cangooroo.Webservice.V2.Operator` em URI absoluta, exemplo: `http://Cangooroo.Webservice.V2.Operator`.

Caso você não possa modificar a URI para contornar essa dificuldade basta suprimir o relatório de alerta da `libxml` passando o parâmetro [`LIBXML_NOWARNING`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/libxml.constants.php) para a função `simplexml_load_string()`

Agora vem o **problema difícil**. A função `simplexml_load_string()` não consegue analisar elementos que estejam em um namespace diferente da raiz do documento.
Isso significa que você conseguira ler `<soap:Envelope>` e `<soap:Body>` mas não conseguirá ler `<createClientResponse>` e seus descendentes.

Isso acontece porque quando [`simplexml_load_string()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php) for usado para analisar um documento cujo a raiz é prefixada faz-se necessário ser informado no parâmetro `$ns` o prefixo ou namespace a ser consultado. Qualquer elemento fora do namespace informado é descartado. E se o parâmetro `$ns` não for informado `simplexml_load_string()` não conseguirá analisar o documento.

Para contornar você pode remover o prefixo `soap` do documento com [`str_ireplace()`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.str-ireplace.php).

```
<?php
$xmlstr = <<< XML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Body>
        <createClientResponse xmlns="http://v2.services.cangooroo.net/">
            <createClientResult>
                <ClientID xmlns="Cangooroo.Webservice.V2.Operator"></ClientID>
                <ClientCode xmlns="Cangooroo.Webservice.V2.Operator"></ClientCode>
                <CompleteName xmlns="Cangooroo.Webservice.V2.Operator">xxxx</CompleteName>
                <Address xmlns="Cangooroo.Webservice.V2.Operator">yyy</Address>
                <Phone1 xmlns="Cangooroo.Webservice.V2.Operator">(11)11111-111</Phone1>
                <Email xmlns="Cangooroo.Webservice.V2.Operator">abc@abc.com.br</Email>
                <NotificationEmail xmlns="Cangooroo.Webservice.V2.Operator">abc@abc.com.br</NotificationEmail>
                <PaymentType xmlns="Cangooroo.Webservice.V2.Operator"></PaymentType>
                <CanSeeVoucher xmlns="Cangooroo.Webservice.V2.Operator"></CanSeeVoucher>
                <CityName xmlns="Cangooroo.Webservice.V2.Operator"></CityName>
                <CountryName xmlns="Cangooroo.Webservice.V2.Operator"></CountryName>
                <BaseId xmlns="Cangooroo.Webservice.V2.Operator">0</BaseId>
                <BaseName xmlns="Cangooroo.Webservice.V2.Operator" />
                <ExternalReference xmlns="Cangooroo.Webservice.V2.Operator"></ExternalReference>
            </createClientResult>
        </createClientResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
XML;

$xml = str_ireplace(['SOAP-ENV:', 'SOAP:'], '', $xmlstr);

$doc = simplexml_load_string($xml, "SimpleXMLElement", LIBXML_NOWARNING );

var_dump( $doc);


?>
```

Que resulta em:

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#1 (1) {
  ["Body"]=>
  object(SimpleXMLElement)#2 (1) {
    ["createClientResponse"]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#3 (1) {
      ["createClientResult"]=>
      object(SimpleXMLElement)#4 (14) {
        ["ClientID"]=>
        object(SimpleXMLElement)#5 (0) {
        }
        ["ClientCode"]=>
        object(SimpleXMLElement)#6 (0) {
        }
        ["CompleteName"]=>
        string(4) "xxxx"
        ["Address"]=>
        string(3) "yyy"
        ["Phone1"]=>
        string(13) "(11)11111-111"
        ["Email"]=>
        string(14) "abc@abc.com.br"
        ["NotificationEmail"]=>
        string(14) "abc@abc.com.br"
        ["PaymentType"]=>
        object(SimpleXMLElement)#7 (0) {
        }
        ["CanSeeVoucher"]=>
        object(SimpleXMLElement)#8 (0) {
        }
        ["CityName"]=>
        object(SimpleXMLElement)#9 (0) {
        }
        ["CountryName"]=>
        object(SimpleXMLElement)#10 (0) {
        }
        ["BaseId"]=>
        string(1) "0"
        ["BaseName"]=>
        object(SimpleXMLElement)#11 (0) {
        }
        ["ExternalReference"]=>
        object(SimpleXMLElement)#12 (0) {
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

<sup>Teste o exemplo no [IDEOne](https://ideone.com/I3rEqK)</sup>

Comment: opa! o soap client eu troquei por um request em curl e ai funcionou , realmente foi um caos kkk