# Converter em JSON uma resposta SOAP

Tags: php, json, xml, soap

Recebo como resposta o seguinte XML

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <obterLoteCupomResponse xmlns="http://ws.pc.gif.com.br/">
            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
            <resultadoLoteCupom versao="1.0">
                <CNPJ>93109437000149</CNPJ>
                <cLote>58735</cLote>
                <dhRecbto>2019-09-17 18:07:28</dhRecbto>
                <sit>100</sit>
                <NFSe>
                    <chvAcessoNFSe>4393109437000149900CF000000007300402234</chvAcessoNFSe>
                    <sit>200</sit>
                    <motivos>
                        <mot>Error1159 Nota fiscal já foi emitida</mot>
                    </motivos>
                </NFSe>
            </resultadoLoteCupom>
        </obterLoteCupomResponse>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Preciso converter em Objetos para acessar as propriedades.
Estou tentando com a função abaixo mas sem sucesso.

```
public static function xml2array($xmlString)
{
    $xml = simplexml_load_string($xmlString);
    $json = json_encode($xml);
    $array = json_decode($json, TRUE);
    return $array;
}
```

Comment: Veja se lhe ajuda https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/410393/137387, a segunda parte de resposta, o problema difícil, se adéqua ao cenário que você está enfrentando.

Comment: @AugustoVasques continua a mesma coisa. Erro "simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 1: parser error : XML declaration allowed only at the start of the document"

Comment: Seu XML está incompleto coloque `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` na primeira linha.

Comment: @AugustoVasques eu recebo ele assim do servidor, não consigo adicionar ou remover nada.

Comment: `$xmlString .= '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>';`. Antes de você mexer com qualquer dado  NFE você tem que validar, eles fornecem o XSD para fazer a validação.

Comment: @AugustoVasques mesma coisa     public static function xml2array($xmlString)
    {        
        $xmlString .= '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>';
        $xmlFormatado = simplexml_load_string($xmlString);
        $json = json_encode($xmlFormatado);
        $array = json_decode($json, TRUE);
        return $array;
    }

Comment: @AugustoVasques sim, a nota fiscal assinada, transmitida e validada esta tudo conforme o XSD. eu só preciso converter essa resposta em objetos pra que possa tomar atitudes internas de acordo com a resposta SOAP retornada. Tanto é que todas as notas validam perfeitamente.

Comment: Achei o erro, seu código funcionando https://repl.it/repls/GenuineTrimOutlier. De uma olhada na quinta linha do XML da pergunta tem uma declaração de cabeçalho XLM fora de contexto

Comment: @AugustoVasques o problema é que não consigo modificar pra retirar aquela linha, notei mesmo que está fora de contexto quando deveria estar no começo do XML.

Answer (score 1):

Tente extrair o contéudo da mensagem para converter, acredito que sua função não esteja funcionando por não entender o xml como válido, se você colocar o contéudo aqui https://codebeautify.org/xmlvalidator ele acusa o erro, tente com o valor do body:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<resultadoLoteCupom versao="1.0">
    <CNPJ>93109437000149</CNPJ>
    <cLote>58735</cLote>
    <dhRecbto>2019-09-17 18:07:28</dhRecbto>
    <sit>100</sit>
    <NFSe>
        <chvAcessoNFSe>4393109437000149900CF000000007300402234</chvAcessoNFSe>
        <sit>200</sit>
        <motivos>
            <mot>Error1159 Nota fiscal já foi emitida</mot>
        </motivos>
    </NFSe>
</resultadoLoteCupom>
```

abraços.