# PHP - Como analisar uma resposta SOAP XML

Tags: php, xml, web-service, soap, wsdl

Estou encontrando dificuldades para analisar dados de uma resposta SOAP utilizando PHP.

Faço a solicitação da seguinte forma:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $urlWebservice);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

E recebo como resposta o seguinte xml:

```
<S:Envelope
xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<S:Header>
    <WorkContext
        xmlns="http://oracle.com/weblogic/soap/workarea/">rO0HBXdRABt3ZWJsb2dpYy5hcHAubW9kdWxvLXdlYi1lYXIAAADWAAAAI3dlYmxvZ2ljLndvcmthcmVhLlN0cmluZ1dvcmtDb250ZXh0NTV2OzM0OQMVR
    </WorkContext>
</S:Header>
<S:Body>
    <ns0:obterClientesResponse
        xmlns:ns0="http://webservice.web.integracao.sascar.com.br/">
        <return>
            <cnpj>12345678912345</cnpj>
            <cpf>0</cpf>
            <idCliente>123456</idCliente>
            <nome>CLIENTE 01</nome>
        </return>
        <return>
            <cnpj>98765432198765</cnpj>
            <cpf>0</cpf>
            <idCliente>654321</idCliente>
            <nome>CLIENTE 02</nome>
        </return>
    </ns0:obterClientesResponse>
```

Estou tentando analisar da seguinte forma, mas sem sucesso:

```
$xmlresponse = simplexml_load_string($response);

foreach ($xmlresponse as $item) {
    echo $item->return->idCliente;
}
```

Agradeço muito qualquer dica que possa me ajudar :)

Comment: Veja se ajuda: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/410379/simplexml-load-com-problema-no-xmlns/410393#410393

Comment: Olá Augusto! Seguindo o exemplo citado, retornou o seguinte: `SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [xmlnS] => http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/ ) [Header] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [WorkContext] =>  ) [Body] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [ns0:obterClientesResponse] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [xmlnns0] => http://webservice.web.integracao.sascar.com.br/ ) [return] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [cnpj] => 12345678987654 [cpf] => 0 [idCliente] => 123456 [nome] => CLIENTE 01) ) ) )`

Alguma dica de como analisar esse retorno? :)

Comment: Você fez a mesma pergunta para o @RicardoPontual. Desculpa parecer grosseiro  mas eu não entendi o significado da pergunta, como assim dica para analisar? Não quer mandar o link um sandbox(https://replit.com/~ ou https://ideone.com/) para que possamos ver o que está acontecendo?

Comment: Olá Augusto!
Me desculpe, acho que me expressei de forma errada na pergunta, vou reformular:

Fiz o ajuste removendo o prefixo conforme sua sugestão no link https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/410379/simplexml-load-com-problema-no-xmlns/410393#410393.

Após remover o prefixo `soap` obtive o retorno conforme adicionei no comentário anterior. Porém ainda não consegui apresentar na tela o resultado esperado ao analisar o `xml`. 

Você consegue identificar o que estou fazendo de errado?
`$xmlresponse->Body->children('ns0', true)->obterClientesResponse->return->idCliente`

Comment: manda um sandbox para ver funcionamento do código.

Comment: Claro, segue link: https://ideone.com/8CIpQA

Comment: Seria isso https://ideone.com/CZFznU

Comment: Maravilha, funcionou perfeitamente. Muito obrigado Augusto!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Primeiro é preciso navegar até o `Body`

`$xmlresponse->children('s', true)->Body`

A seguir ler os "filhos" com `children()`, que deve retornar o "obterClientesResponse". A partir daí chegar em "return". Ficaria assim:

```
$returns = $xmlresponse->children('s', true)->Body->obterClientesResponse->return
foreach ($returns as $return) {
    echo $return->idCliente;
}
```

Note que o seu XML tem os namespaces prefixados nas tags, pode ser necessário informar isso, por exemplo `...Body->children('ns0', true)->obterClientesResponse->return`

**EDIT:** reproduzi a mesma respostas e testei. Foi necessário usar `children` antes de cada nó para que funcionasse corretamente, ficou assim:

```
$returns = $response
             ->children('S', true)->Body
             ->children('ns0', true)->obterClientesResponse
             ->children()->return;

foreach ($returns as $return) {
    echo "\n ". $return->idCliente;
}
```

Foi testado e pode ver funcionando aqui: [https://onlinephp.io/](https://onlinephp.io/c/09fe0)

Comment: Olá Ricardo!

Fiz o teste conforme sua dica, porém ainda não obtive o resultado esperado.

Ao escrever `print_r($xmlresponse);` apresenta a seguinte resposta: **SimpleXMLElement Object ( )**.

Comment: olá Roberto. isso é o eseprado, o `$xmlresponse` é um objeto que aponta para um node :)  como comentei, precisa ir navegando em da "childeren" ou os filhos de cada node até chegar no node que precisa

Comment: Olá Ricardo! Entendi, mas mesmo seguindo sua dica não consigo analisar as informações do xml. Por favor veja a linha abaixo se estou fazendo corretamente: 
`echo "Cliente ID: " .$xmlresponse->children('S', true)->Body->children('ns0', true)->obterClientesResponse->return->idCliente`

Com esta linha não apresenta nada na tela :(

Comment: @Roberto agora tive tempo pra fazer um teste, veja a resposta... foi preciso adicioar `children` antes do "return"

Answer (score 1):

Sei que minha resposta não é sobre o tratamento do XML

Mas como vi que vc ta fazendo um integração sascar, talvez isso não seja necessário

Para realizar requisições  para o web service da integração da sascar eu fiz o seguinte

```
$client = new SoapClient($urlWebservice);
$data['usuario'] = $user; 
$data['senha'] = $password;
$result = $client->obterClientes($data);
```

Ele retornar uma array com os objetos

Caso queria transformar tudo em array adicione

```
$resultArray = json_decode(json_encode(result), true);
```

Comment: Olá Bruno. Bacana, não sabia que poderia fazer dessa forma, realmente é muito mais simples.